# Can a client have multiple server?

Tags: linux, sockets

I have 3 machines running parallely, out of which 1 and 2 have already socket conection for communcation. In which machine 1 is client and machine 2 is server.

Now I have to implement machine 3 which will also be server. Machine 1 will be client for machine 2 and 3 same time.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

One application can have multiple sockets (server or client, doesn't matter). Each socket is bound to a specific address and a specific function (server/client), but if you open multiple sockets you can mix them as you wish, they hold no relation.

In your case, M2 and M3 will both have one listener socket each, and M1 will have two sender sockets in the same application. Note that the sockets will operate completely in parallel (they share no data).

Comment: Hi, Mephy Thanks for response. As i am very new to socket programming i am asking "M2 and M3 will both have one listener socket each" will M2 and M3 have same socket address or differnt port or both socket address as well as port will be different.

Comment: Each socket is completely independent. You could run them in the same port if you wish (it is common to do this if its the same application). The address you can't choose, its the IP address of the machine.